# iterate over Excel file in perl using Spreadsheet::Read

Tags: perl, spreadsheet

I am trying to parse data from an excel file (can be xlsx or xls).

I already know which worksheets I want to get, so I would like to iterate over them and extract the data from them.

My code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::Read;
use Getopt::Long;

my $inputfile;

GetOptions (
  'i=s' => \$inputfile,
);

die 'missing input file' unless $inputfile;

my $workbook  = ReadData ($inputfile, debug => 9);
my @worksheets = (1);
foreach (@worksheets) {
  my $sheet = $workbook->[$_-1];

  next unless $sheet;

  my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $sheet->row_range();
  my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $sheet->col_range();
  for my $row ($row_min .. $row_max) {

  }
}
```

However, I get the following :

```
Can't call method "row_range" on unblessed reference at perl/parse_test.pl line 22.
```

I'm very new to perl, and don't understand yet the intricacies of hashes, arrays and references.

Comment: Please always `use warnings` in preference to the command-line `-w` option. Using both is superfluous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First don't use array if you don't need it,

`my @sheet = $workbook->[$_-1];` => `my $sheet = $workbook->[$_-1];`

Print `$sheet` reference to check instance of `$sheet` if error still occurs.

```
next unless $sheet;
print ref($sheet), "\n";
```

It look like your data should be accessed in another way, this is from [http://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::Read#Data-structure](http://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet%3a%3aRead#Data-structure)

```
$book = [
  # Entry 0 is the overall control hash
  { sheets  => 2,
    sheet   => {
      "Sheet 1"  => 1,
      "Sheet 2"  => 2,
      },
    type    => "xls",
    parser  => "Spreadsheet::ParseExcel",
    version => 0.59,
    },
  # Entry 1 is the first sheet
  { label   => "Sheet 1",
    maxrow  => 2,
    maxcol  => 4,
    cell    => [ undef,
      [ undef, 1 ],
      [ undef, undef, undef, undef, undef, "Nugget" ],
      ],
    A1      => 1,
    B5      => "Nugget",
    },
  # Entry 2 is the second sheet
  { label   => "Sheet 2",
    :
    :
]
```

so if you want to read label from `$sheet` it would be `$sheet->{label}`, and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the code. It is already a $. I'll update the question

Comment: Updated, `$sheet` is plain hash and not an object which has its own methods.

Comment: @szabgab what is wrong with plain cpan? This is second time I've seen such edit.

Comment: search.cpan.org is closed source, metacpan.org is open source, but the main issue was that the link lead to a specific version that will be deleted sometime in the future and then the link becomes broken. The one I added always leads to the latest.
(BTW search.cpan.org is not "plain cpan" it is an add-on to cpan.org just as metacpan.org is an add-on)

Comment: @szabgab is there some article about who is who in perl infrastructure? Btw, `css` looks way better for search.cpan, and wonder why meta is not under cpan => `meta.cpan.org`?

Comment: I guess whether `css` looks better is a personal opinion, but if you have ideas how to improve that for MetaCPAN, I am sure you could make a case there. (see About link at the bottom of https://metacpan.org/ )

Who is who - I don't know about any such article, but might be interesting to put one together. If you are interested to discuss this pls. send me a mail to gabor@szabgab.com 

Finally, I don't know why not meta.cpan.org. Maybe it is something to do with politics or ownership.

Comment: @mpapec There's an interesting (and fairly current) summary of who owns and/or hosts various Perl sites here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tpf-marketing/m4CTt_MARwo/X_z2Av5R9-YJ

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the following:

```
@sheet->row_range
```

You cannot use a method on a non-object. Object must be a reference, i.e. a scalar. It should start with a `$`, not `@`.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the code. It is already a $. I'll update the question.